# I managed to include a video with media9. Can I make a link to save the file?

Tags: pdftex, media9, embedfile

I need to display a video as a media9 object, but, under it, display a link where the user can save the file.

I managed to to create a video playerwith the following script:

```
\pdfminorversion=5 
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\pdfobjcompresslevel=2

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{attachfile}

\inputencoding{utf8}

\begin{document}
[...]

\includemedia[
width=0.6\linewidth,height=0.3375\linewidth, % 16:9
activate=pageopen,
addresource=output.mp4,
flashvars={
    src=output.mp4
    &scaleMode=letterbox
    &controlBarMode=docked
    &autoPlay=false
    &loop=false
    &volume=1.0
    &controlBarAutoHide=false}
]{\includegraphics{video.png}}{StrobeMediaPlayback.swf}

[...]

\end{document}
```

I tried `attachfile`, but it would not work as the embedded file (output.mp4) is not an anottation. I tried `embedfile`, but it would just reembed the file.

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` (having a`\begin{document}`)and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`media9` provides **`attachfiles`** as a package or command option ; no additional package needed.

This lets you download the embedded files from the PDF or open them in an external application via the Attachments panel of A-Reader. See the documentation on [↗page 7](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media9/doc/media9.pdf#page=7).

Fore easy access to the Attachments panel, you could insert a "download" button next to the video. This also works in other viewers, not just A-Reader.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}

\raisebox{\depth}{%
  \includemedia[
    width=0.6\linewidth,height=0.2\linewidth,
    addresource=\jobname.tex, % not a media file, just a sample
    attachfiles
  ]{\fbox{Click!}}{VPlayer.swf}%
}
\mbox{\Acrobatmenu{ShowHideFileAttachment}{\Large\faicon{download}}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I added '/usepackage[attachfiles]{media9}' but still, I couldn´t create a link inside de pdf. Some users will face difficulties on acessing bookmarks.

Comment: What about a single button next to the video display? (See the edit.)

Comment: I wish I could have a "save file" button, but I think this options workswell enought and maybe it is even better because there you may open it on a separate player or save it. Thanks!